# How to use Mission Control with multiple monitors?

Tags: macos, display, mission-control

I'm using a MPBr + Yosemite with 2x 27" monitors.

I also use parallels with Win8 for development.

I'm hoping to have 2x 'spaces'. (I'm not sure if that's the best way to describe this). Each space uses BOTH monitors.

1st space (`space_1`) is my OSX space. This is where I will do my email/slack/chrome.
2nd space (`space_2`) is Parallels in full screen mode, which will extend over both monitors.

My outcome is this:

- When i click on the chrome or email or slack icon in my dock, *BOTH* monitors display the content of space_1. (eg. email/slack/chrome windows).
- When I click on the windows application in my dock, everything in space_1 disappears away .. and suddenly my windows environment takes over *BOTH* monitors ... and this is what I call space_2.

I'm trying to do this with Mission Control but it's not working right. When i click on a mac app or a windows app (in the dock) only one of the two monitors changes .. not both :(

It's very frustrating.

Is this possible? Can what I'm asking, be done?

Help me AskDifferent, you're my only hope.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found this about 8 years late, but…
System Prefs > Mission Control > 'Displays have separate spaces' - switch off.

Key commands, by default, will be Ctrl/1 & Ctrl/2. If you look in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control you will see these are defined by default as you enable each extra Space, but they are not enabled by default.

This lets you then set affinity for Parallels to Space 2.
Switch to Space 2. Launch Parallels. Right click the icon in the dock > Options > This Desktop.

You can either set the same affinity for *all* Mac apps to Space 1, or just be certain to always be on 1 when you launch them.

The only thing about this setup is you cannot use true fullscreen. You can drag your Windows desktop to take up the entirety of both displays, but if you switch to actual fullscreen, one display will go black.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use one "space" and place the parallels apps on monitor 2 and mac apps on monitor 1?

Spaces is like completely new environment of all monitors attached and can't be used in different way.

Maybe this question is a bit old and it's available since Yosemite and El Capitan.